# Help understanding and translating my private network genesis file parameters with config.go variables

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am modifying the file config.go in the geth project for a private blockchain.

Here are the config.go variables

```
// MainnetChainConfig is the chain parameters to run a node on the main network.
MainnetChainConfig = &ChainConfig{
    ChainId:        big.NewInt(1),
    HomesteadBlock: big.NewInt(1150000),
    DAOForkBlock:   big.NewInt(1920000),
    DAOForkSupport: true,
    EIP150Block:    big.NewInt(2463000),
    EIP150Hash:     common.HexToHash("0x2086799aeebeae135c246c65021c82b4e15a2c451340993aacfd2751886514f0"),
    EIP155Block:    big.NewInt(2675000),
    EIP158Block:    big.NewInt(2675000),
    ByzantiumBlock: big.NewInt(math.MaxInt64), // Don't enable yet

    Ethash: new(EthashConfig),
}
```

If I give an example of my test network

```
{
"config": {
    "chainId": 87079082075,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
},
"nonce": "0x0000087079082075",
"timestamp": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"extraData": "0x00",
"gasLimit": "0x8000000",
"difficulty": "0x400",
"mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333"
```

Some parameters / variables are straight forward to map.

Here is my attempt

```
ChainId big.NewInt(87079082075),
HomesteadBlock: big.NewInt(0),
DAOForkBlock:   big.NewInt(0),
DAOForkSupport: true,
EIP150Block:    big.NewInt(0),
EIP150Hash:     common.HexToHash("NotSureWhereToGetThisValue"),
EIP155Block:    big.NewInt(0),
EIP158Block:    big.NewInt(0),
ByzantiumBlock: big.NewInt(math.MaxInt64)
```

I then get confused with the values in [util.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/09777952ee476ff80d4b6e63b5041ff5ca0e441b/params/util.go#L25) and will it overwrite these values in config.go.

I also do not see in config.go the values associated with the other genesis file parameters like difficulty and gaslimit.  I think they are updated in protocol_params.go can someone confirm I am observing the code correctly and on the right track.